# Calculate the 95th percentile of a population from a set of 95th percentiles calculated on subsets

Tags: distributions, quantiles

I need to calculate the 95th percentile of large collection of streamflow measurements.  The resolution of the measurements was originally hourly, but then were transformed into daily means.  There are approximately 50 - 60 years of daily means.  Unfortunately, I don't have access to the daily means.

What I do have access to is 365 values representing the 95th percentile (and other percentiles - 5th, 25th, 50th, 75th, and more) for different calendar dates.  To be specific, I have the 95th percentile value for 50-60 January 1sts, I have the 95th percentile value for 50-60 January 2nds, and so on.

Is there a method to calculate a representative 95th percentile of the data set from the information I have available to me?

Since this is a data set of streamflow measurements, I was assuming a Log Pearson Type III distribution for the underlying data.

Comment: The distributions vary across the year; you'd need not only some model for the conditional distributions, but how they vary over time.

Comment: @Glen_b, Are you assuming they vary over time?  I think the USGS uses annual peak flows and the Lop Pearson III distribution to calculated recurrence intervals  and other flow statistics.  I would think since there are using values from different years they believe the population of extreme values across all these years follows the same distribution.  Would this not be so of all values?

Comment: I assume they vary from month to month. Why would peak flow be the same in January and July, or March and September?

Comment: Of course the min, max, median values vary from month to month, year to year.  I thought you were saying the distribution of the values varies from year to year.  I find that somewhat possible, but the calculations the USGS performs for recurrence intervals suggests the underlying distribution of annual peak flows (regardless of the month/day they occur in) follows (mostly closely) a single distribution, LP3.  Why would the daily means for a 30 year record not also follow a single distribution?  I have 365 95th percentile values, one for each julian day - do they follow a single distribution?

Comment: The overall distribution would be akin to a mixture of the daily distributions (not though not actually, since each distribution is represented exactly once). In that sense you could perhaps treat it as something which you could compute a 95th percentile of. But I don't see how you could get that information out of the daily 95th percentiles without having all the distributional information.